# Elasticsearch exited unexpectedly, with exit code 1

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube

[enter image description here][1]

I am trying to start up Sonarqube on window server, and whenever I try to run `startsonar.bat`, this error shows up

> Elasticsearch exited unexpectedly, with exit code 1

- Killing all running Java processes on your machine
- Deleting the /data/es8 folder from your SonarQube installation directory
- Restarting

  Feb 22, 2024 12:36:03 PM sun.til. locale-provider. LocaleProviderAdapter 
  O
  WARNING: COMPAT locale provider will be removed in a future release
  ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at D: \ISO\ sonarqube-10.4.0.87286\ sonarqube-10.4.0.87286\logs\sona rqube. log
  ERROR: Elasticsearch exited unexpectedly, with exit code 1 2024.02.22 12:36:09 WARN app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]:
  2024.02.22 12:36:09 INFO app[] [o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [ElasticSearch] is stopped
  2024.02.22 12:36:09 ERROR app[][o.s.a.p. EsManagedProcess] Failed to check status hava. lang.RuntimeException: thread waiting for the response was interrunted
  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:901)
  at org.elasticsearch.client.Restclient.performRequest(RestClient.java:300)
  at org-elasticsearch. client.RestClient.performRequest (RestClient. java: 288)
  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelclient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelclient.java:2699)
  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient-java:2171)
  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient-performRequest(RestHighLevelclient.java:2137)
  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient-performequestAndarseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:2105)
  at org.elasticsearch.client.ClusterClient.health (ClusterClient. java: 151)
  at org. sonar. application.es.EsConnectorImpl.getClusterHealthStatus(EsConnectorImp1.java:79)
  at org. sonar -application process. EsManagedProcess.checkStatusEsManagedProcess.java:92) at org.sonar.application-process.EsManagedProcess-checkOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:77) org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.isOperational (EsManagedProcess. java
  at org .sonar .application -process.ManagedProcessHandler.refreshState(ManagedProcessHandler-java:223)
  at org.sonar .application .process.Managed rocessHandler$Even tWatcher. run (Managed roces sHandler - java: 288)
  aused by: java.lang. InterruptedException: null
  at java.base/java. lang.Object.wait (Native Method) at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Object. java: 366)
  at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Object-java:359)
  at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.get (BasicFuture-java: 82)
  at org.apache.http.1mpl.nio.client.FutureWrapper.get[FutureWrapper.java:70)
  at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:296)
  12
  common Frames omitted
  2024.02.22 12:36:09 INFO app[|[o.s.a. SchedulerImp1] SonarQube is stopped

  ```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUDca.jpg
  ```

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.